# How to detect when a marker is found in AR.js

Tags: three.js, aframe, artoolkit, ar.js

I'm trying to detect when a marker if found/lost in ar.js, while using a-frame.

From what I see in the [source code](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/blob/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js), when the marker is found, a 'getMarker' event should be fired, moreover artoolkit seems to dispatch a markerFound event.

I tried to listen to those events on the `<a-scene>`, or on the `<a-marker>`, but it seems I'm either mistaken, or i need to get deeper to the `arController`, or `arToolkit` objects.

When i log the scene, or the marker, i only get references to the attributes, which don't seem to have the above objects attached.(like `marker.arController`, or `marker.getAttribute('artoolkitmarker').arController`)

Did anybody tried this and have any tips how to do this ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[PR303](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/pull/303) introduces events when a marker is found and lost

- `markerFound`
- `markerLost`

You can use them by simply adding an event listener:

```
anchorRef.addEventListener("markerFound", (e)=>{ // your code here}
```

with a simple setup like this:

```
<a-marker id="anchor">
  <a-entity>
</a-marker>
```

example [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NLVMOo). 
Please note, that as of sep 18', you need to use the `dev` branch to use the above.

---

**ORIGINAL ANWSER** - in case you want to do it manually

---

Detecting if the marker is found is possible by checking if the marker is visible when needed (other event, or on tick): `if(document.querySelector("a-marker").object3D.visible == true)`

For example:

```
init: function() {
   this.marker = document.querySelector("a-marker")
   this.markerVisible = false
},
tick: function() {
   if (!this.marker) return
   if (this.marker.object3D.visible) {
      if (!this.markerVisible) {
         // marker detected
         this.markerVisible = true
      }
   } else {
      if (this.markerVisbile) {
         // lost sight of the marker
         this.markerVisible = false
      }
   }
}
```

---

As adrian li noted, it doesn't work with `a-marker-camera`, only with `a-markers`

Comment: Also related, https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/issues/217 and https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/pull/303. This needs to be fixed within the AR.js library; until then it isn't possible without checking visibility aggressively.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy thanks for the information, i've subscribed to the pull request (#303), if it gets pulled, i'll modify the anwser :)

Comment: @DonMcCurdy thanks for the tip, i've modified the anwser as the branch was merged with Jerome's `dev` branch.

Comment: is there this also for three.js version?

Answer (score 0):

I went with a dirty hack diving into the internals, bear in mind that what I've provided might not suffice because the event get's called every time the marker is found, sadly I couldn't find an event to hook into for markers being lost.

```
const arController = document.querySelector("a-scene").systems.arjs._arSession.arContext.arController;

arController.addEventListener("getMarker", (evt) => {
    const markerType = evt.data.type;
    const patternType = 0;

    //console.log("onMarkerFound!!");

    if (markerType == patternType) {
        //console.log("onMarkerFound out pattern!!");

        //Do stuff...
    }
});
```