# Display HTML Element with AR.js (Augmented Reality)

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

I want display HTML Element with AR.js.

The code is below. and AR is working well.

But, 'Hello world' div element has been displayed always!
I want to hide this div element. and only display it when the marker is detected.

How can I do it？

---

demo URL https://pano-mixer360.com/sandbox/demo

marker: Hiro

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <%= javascript_include_tag "vendor-js/aframe/dist/aframe-v0.6.0.min.js", media: "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "vendor-js/html2canvas/dist/html2canvas.min.js", media: "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "vendor-js/aframe-html-shader/dist/aframe-html-shader.min.js", media: "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "vendor-js/aframe-mouse-cursor-component/dist/aframe-mouse-cursor-component.min.js", media: "all" %>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px; overflow:hidden;">
<!-- load AR.js -->
<script src="https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>

<div id="profile" style="color: greenyellow; width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: red; position: absolute; top: 00px; left: 0;">
Hello world!
</div>

<!-- set AR.js to AFrame -->
<a-scene embedded arjs="debugUIEnabled:false;">
  <!-- set marker -->
  <a-marker preset="hiro">
    <a-plane position="0.43 1.17 -1.48" rotation="-72 85 -88" scale="1 1 1" material="shader:html;target: #profile;"></a-plane>
  </a-marker>

  <!-- set camera -->
  <a-entity camera></a-entity>
</a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect when marker is found in AR.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44799413/how-to-detect-when-marker-is-found-in-ar-js)

Answer (score 0):

Just put it behind the canvas element by adding `z-index: -2` to the div element's style.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this component https://github.com/supereggbert/aframe-htmlembed-component.

For example try to add this to the a-scene.

```
<a-entity  htmlembed>

<div id="profile" style="color: greenyellow; width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: red; position: absolute; top: 00px; left: 0;">
Hello world!
</div>

</a-entity>
```

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<div class="helloworld">Hello world!</div>
```

css:

```
<style>
.helloworld {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 10;
  color: greenyellow; 
  width: 300px; 
  height: 300px; 
  background-color: red; 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 00px; left: 0;
}
```

if you want it to do interactions with javascript you should use window.onload