# Aframe: smoothing position and rotation?

Tags: javascript, html, aframe, ar.js

I have been experimenting a bit with Aframe and AR.js. For augmented reality applications, a common problem is that the object placed on a marker becomes quite 'jittery' or 'jerky'. I have done some research into the problem already and it appears that a possible way to address this issue is to smooth the rotation and the position over several frames. Unfortunately, tutorials on doing so are virtually nonexistent, and I am just starting to get to grips with Html/Javascript.

Hence my question: Would you know if it is possible to have a function in an aframe entity which extracts the position and rotation, smooths them, and then passes them on to (I imagine) a child entity which uses those smoothed values for placement?

```
<a-entity position="0 0 0" rotation="0 0 0" >
   <a-video Mysmoothingfunction src="#video" width="3.5" height="2"></a-video>
</a-entity>
```

I could imagine that the start might look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   AFRAME.registerComponent("listener", {
    schema : 
    {
        stepFactor : {
            type : "number",
            default : 0.05
        }
    },
   tick: function() {
       this.getProperty("position"); // something like this?
      }
</script>
```

Would you have any idea how to tackle that issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your description sounds like [linear interpolation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3.lerp). Utilizing it here should be simple:

Once the **marker** is visible, get the previous **video** position / rotation, and make an approximation using the actual **marker** position / rotation. Then update the **video**, with the approximated values.

The approximation should ease the 'jitter'. In this case, i'll be using the [THREE `lerp`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3.lerp) function.
If you're not familiar with [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation) then think of it as a method of approximation using linear functions (this may be highly imprecise, but it's how i think of it).

The code (attached to the marker) looks like this:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("listener", {
  init: function() {
    this.target = document.querySelector('#target'); // your video
    this.prevPosition = null; // initially there is no position or rotation
    this.prevRotation = null;
  },

  tick: function() {
    if (this.el.object3D.visible) {
      this.target.setAttribute('visible', 'true')

      if(!this.prevPosition && !this.prevRotation) { 
        // there are no values to lerp from - set the initial values
        this.target.setAttribute('position', this.el.getAttribute('position'))
        this.target.setAttribute('rotation', this.el.getAttribute('rotation'))
      } else {
        // use the previous values to get an approximation 
        this.target.object3D.position.lerp(this.prevPosition, 0.1)

        // this (below) may seem ugly, but the rotation is a euler, not a THREE.Vector3, 
        // so to use the lerp function i'm doing some probably unnecessary conversions
        let rot = this.target.object3D.rotation.toVector3().lerp(this.prevRotation, 0.1)
        this.target.object3D.rotation.setFromVector3(rot)
      }
      // update the values
      this.prevPosition = this.el.object3D.position
      this.prevRotation = this.el.object3D.rotation
    } else {
     // the marker dissapeared - reset the values
     this.target.setAttribute('visible', 'false')
     this.prevPosition = null;
     this.prevRotation = null;
   }
  }
})
```

You can notice im setting the values of the `object3D` instead of the official [API](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/introduction/javascript-events-dom-apis.html#updating-a-component-with-setattribute) (`setAttribute()` / `getAttribute()`). It should be faster, which is desirable when making changes within the `tick()` function.

[Here](https://glitch.com/~arjs-aframe-lerp) is a glitch (one box is interpolated, its moving quite smoothly).

Comment: Soon there will be an event when the marker is found, or lost, more on it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44799413/how-to-detect-when-a-marker-is-found-in-ar-js).

Comment: Hey @Piotr Adam Milewski, I really like the code you posted above. While trying to understand and maybe use it, I discovered two problems. I created an issue over at the AR.js repo to discuss this: https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/issues/467 Maybe you want to jump in.